# VSCode Ruby RuboCop formatter removes focused specs `fit` -> `it`

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rubocop

I've been happily using https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby in VSCode which has been auto-formatting my code on save, until this was merged https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop-rspec/pull/1109 (which is great in itself).

Now when I save a Rspec file with a focused spec, it removes it! eg

On saving `fit "something" do`, it updates it to `it 'something'`! (It does not remove disabled specs `xit`)

`vscode-ruby` config:

```
    "ruby.intellisense": "rubyLocate",
    "ruby.useLanguageServer": true,
    "ruby.codeCompletion": "rcodetools",
    "ruby.format": "rubocop", // this line causes the formatter to kick in
    "ruby.lint": {
        "rubocop": true
    },
```

#### Options

1. I can bypass this by adding `# rubocop:disable RSpec/Focus` to the end, but that is annoying
2. I can disable the cop in my local `.rubocop.yml` file, but then

   1. either have a local diff, and lose the check against all files when running `rubocop` on the command line
   2. have to check it in and everyone loses the check
3. AFAICT there is no command-line option to disable a cop. The inverse of `only` would be good!
4. But even if that option was present, can `vscode-ruby` be configured to modify the command line options?
5. Others?

Comment: I've suggested `exclude` rubocop command line option https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/issues/9493

Answer (score 1):

To have `ruby-lsp` extension still fix most auto-correctable offences on save in VS Code, but allow for focussed tests to still work, you could rely on an extra safety next in your continuous integration environment.

Disable the cop in `.rubocop.yml`:

```yaml
RSpec/Focus:
  Enabled: false
```

and modify the focus configuration in `rails_helper.rb` to say:

```rb
if ENV["CI"]
  config.before(:example, :focus) { |example| raise "Focused spec found at #{example.location}" }
else
  config.filter_run_when_matching :focus
end
```

I figured this out via [Stephanie Viccari’s blog post](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/avoid-merging-rspec-focused-tests#option-2-use-rspec-to-catch-focused-tests).

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have solved itself!

So I guess some dependency was updated that "fixes" it, for now...

I will see if I can find what it is.

Comment: And it came back :-(

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. I've recently added Ruby LSP extension. It worked great for about a week or two, but today I've noticed the same issue as described in your question.

My solution was to disable the extension.

Comment: My work-around is to move the cursor after saving which prevents it from updating the file!